# Errors appearing after updating Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As the title suggests, after I updated Android Studio to the latest version, I am getting all sorts of errors in places that were normally fine before the update.

What is wrong here?
[image: Image of Errors]

Comment: Have you tried restarting android studio?

Comment: I restarted aswell but still i am still getting error

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** - Try clean and rebuild option!! 
**Option 2** - Try invalidate cache and restart. 
**Option 3** (last option) - Try rolling back to previous version of gradle plugin.

Comment: I did the first and second one but I am not sure about the third one how to do that I am quite new to android studio